# Not able to move the data to next line after 80 Characters

Tags: java, stringbuilder

```
String PoDescriptionOfGoods = extractedData.get(counter).getPoDescriptionOfGoods();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PoDescriptionOfGoods);
int i = 0;
while ((i = sb.indexOf(" ", i + 80)) != -1) {
    sb.replace(i, i + 1, "\n");
}
searsData.add(sequence.concat(PoGoods.concat(PoDescriptionOfGoods)));
```

I am fetching `PoDescriptionOfGoods` of goods from database and wants to move it to next line in the report if it crosses 80 characters.

Comment: Why did you give tags for all the languages in the world?

Comment: Really, why did'nt you pay attention to the language tags?

Comment: @Haris, All the languages in the world? Aren't you exagerating?. But I do get your pont ... :)

Comment: @iharob, not in a very cheerful mood, so just wrote. -_-

Comment: Because person with knowledge of any language can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign `sb` back to original variable:

```
PoDescriptionOfGoods = sb.toString()
```

Additionally, you'll have to modify the loop so it starts on 160 on the next try and so on. Currently you'll change all spaces after position 80 to new line.